# Adding Items To Shopping Cart Django Python

Tags: python, django

EDIT
When I click add to cart this is the output to the terminal

```
[22/Mar/2016 07:07:44] "GET /store/add/7 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[22/Mar/2016 07:07:44] "GET /store/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4888
```

I have two function one adds items to cart and one removes.

I am thinking the problem is my URL request is not being formed right. So I would appreciate someone who is more experienced than me to explaining to me what the expected URL should be.

I am creating my URL like this,

```
url(r'^add/(\d+)', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),  
    url(r'^remove/(\d+)', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
    url(r'^cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),
```

The the link to add items to the cart is in a base.html file and looks like this,

```
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
         <span class="storefront_add_to_cart">
             <a href="{% url 'add_to_cart' book.id %}">[Add to Cart]</a>
         </span>
         {% endif %}
```

So when you add or remove an item from the cart it calls the respective functions.

Views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request,book_id):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
            else :
                try:
                    cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, active = True)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    cart = Cart.objects.create(user = request.user)
                    cart.save()
                    cart.add_to_cart(book_id)
                    return redirect('cart')
                else:
                    return redirect('index')


def remove_from_cart(request, book_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(pk = book_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass 
        else:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, active = True)
            cart.remove_from_cart(book_id)
        return redirect('cart')
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

When I click add to cart the url looks like this (which gives me the error)

```
http://localhost:8000/store/add/4
```

When I click remove from cart the url looks like this but I don't get any errors. (The item in the cart stays and will not remove.)

```
http://localhost:8000/store/cart/%7B%20url%20'remove_from_cart'%20item.book.id%20%%7D
```

And in case it helps here is the respective models in models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self): 
            return "%s" % (self.user)

    def add_to_cart(self, book_id):
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        try:
            preexisting_order = BookOrder.objects.get(book=book, cart=self)
            preexisting_order.quantity += 1
            preexisting_order.save()
        except BookOrder.DoesNotExist:
            new_order = BookOrder.objects.create(
                book=book,
                cart=self,
                quantity=1
                )
            new_order.save()

            def __unicode__(self):
                return "%s" % (self.book_id)


    def remove_from_cart(self, book_id):
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        try:
            preexisting_order = BookOrder.objects.get(book=book, cart=self)
            if preexisting_order.quantity > 1:
                preexisting_order.quantity -= 1
                preexisting_order.save()
            else:
                preexisting_order.delete()
        except BookOrder.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Comment: Your code does not return anything if the user is not authenticated. That is what is causing the error

Comment: I am logged in. Are you saying that is the problem even though I am logged in. And does the url for when it removes look correct?

Comment: If that is true, then you are hitting an ObjectDoesNotExist exception. In django, a view always has to return some response. So make sure you follow that criteria

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you mind giving me a few pointers on how to trouble shoot this?

Comment: For starters, you can add print statements in the code and check where you hit the exception

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets tackle this one at at time.

To start off with, you need to use the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator); you should also not accept invalid books to be added to the cart (which you are currently checking at the database level, and this error is not being displayed to the customer).

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def add_to_cart(request,book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
    cart,created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, active=True)
    cart.add_to_cart(book_id)
    return redirect('cart')
```

Next, you need to fix your *template* where you are generating the link to remove items from your cart.  Your link should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'remove_from_cart' args=(item.book.id,) %}">Remove item</a>
```

In your models, you have two `__unicode__` methods, I assume this is an error in copy-paste, otherwise you need to remove the second one, which won't work anyway since its indented into the `add_to_cart` method, from your `models.py`.

You don't need that method anyway, you should keep the entire logic in your views.  Here is the revised method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages

from .models import Cart, BookOrder, Book

@login_required
def add_to_cart(request,book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)
    cart,created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, active=True)
    order,created = BookOrder.objects.get_or_create(book=book,cart=cart)
    order.quantity += 1
    order.save()
    messages.success(request, "Cart updated!")
    return redirect('cart')
```

Comment: First off thank you so much for being so kind and taking the time to help me.  I apologize for my ignorance.  Are you suggesting I remove the add_to_cart def out of model completely and replace the method in the view completely with your add_to_cart? I tried replacing it in the view and leaving the model. and removing the model and view then adding your method in the view. Both ways I get a 500 error and this IntegrityError at /store/add/4
NOT NULL constraint failed: store_bookorder.quantity

Comment: This is because quantity in your models doesn't have a default value; so when you run `get_or_create` and don't supply a value for quantity, you get this exception.

The easiest way to solve this is to give quantity a default value in your models.py.

Comment: Thank you so much I got add_to_cart to work. I cant seem to get remove_from_cart to work. Leaving the methods the same and adding the link you provided keeps giving me syntax error but I do not see the error. args=(item.book.id)  Could we not just rewrite the remove function all in the view the same way we rewrote the add function?

Comment: Of course, but StackOverflow is not a code writing service; give it a best effort on your part, and if you run into an issue - please open a new question. Make sure you close this question [by accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) first, if the solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the type of `book_id`. It will be 'unicode'. Therefore the comparison `Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)` will not work.

You need to type cast it to integer.

use: `book_id = int(book_id)`

before

`book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: The URL regex specifies `\d+`. So I guess it is taken as int by default?

Comment: This actually makes sense thank you. Would I do that in the model then? Or in this view?  so in place of that do book = int(book_id)

Comment: @wuno: you cant do it in view iteself

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Although URL regex specifies `\d+` the datatype will still be unicode. You should check it yourself. I tested it before posting my answer.

Comment: I am saying this because I have been using this a lot and I never had the need to convert it to int before querying

Comment: But if this is the problem then why does my url still get the int? In my question you can see the url gets the value 4. I am returning the book_id in the model of add_to_cart like this, def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.book_id)  - it is in my question above

Comment: @wuno: in your view write a print statement `print type(book_id)`. The you will see `<type 'unicode'>` in terminal. And yes your URL gets 4 but it is unicoded string not an `integer`. Type cast it to integer before using it. If it solves your problem then accept this answer so that others know what the problem was.

Comment: Yes you were right this showed in terminal <type 'unicode'> will you please update your example to fix this with my code in the question?

Comment: Wait, so I am printing book_id and book out. print type(book_id)
       print type(book) These were the results <type 'unicode'>
<class 'store.models.Book'> is book showing what it would need to for this to work?

Comment: edited .. just type cast to integer before fetching object.

Comment: This still does not make sense though. Were casting book to int but then later in the function where still calling book_id in the cart.add_to_cart(book_id). I think there is something else here causing this problem. Will you please take a loot at the code I provided.

Comment: I think you are not getting what he is trying to say. You just have to convert the type of book_id to integer then only you can get the book you required as the pk is int.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the indentations here.

```
def add_to_cart(request,book_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass  
        else :
            try:
                cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, active = True)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                cart = Cart.objects.create(user = request.user)
                cart.save()
            cart.add_to_cart(book_id)
        return redirect('cart')
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Comment: My linter does give me an error. But its not that. The error I do get is variable book is assigned but never used. on this line book = Book.objects.get(pk = book_id) | What I don't understand is why because I am following along with a tutorial from Udemy and this works for him.

Comment: You can ignore this error about unused variable because you actually need the `ObjectDoesnotExist` exception for the logic of this view.

Answer (score 0):

```
def AddToCart (request, id):

    menu = product.objects.get(id=id)
    user= userModel.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    
    if item.objects.get(ProductID = id,user = request.user.id):
        update = item.objects.get(ProductID=id,user=request.user.id)
        update.quantity += 1
        update.save()
        
    
    else :
        add =item(ProductID=menu, quantity=1, user=register)
        add.save()
        
    

    return redirect(Home)
```